# how to set the moved bone to original location?

Tags: bones

I moved the bone in post mode but I want to reset what I have moved, I selected the bone and pressed alt + r, it's not working.  How can I reset the bone I moved? I can not undo it as there are too many steps in the history.

blender2.81

Answer (score 0):

Go to pose mode, select the bone, and go to the search tab. Search "Clear pose transforms" and it should do the trick.

Comment: where is search tab